# i have disabled autovacuum on a table autovacuum process running for that table

Tags: postgresql-12

I have disabled autovacuum on a table. We are running vacuum manually to speedup process. But I still see autovacuum process running for that table. I am using postgres 12.10
please share your thought

Comment: You might want to add some details to your question, specifically, how did you disable autovacuum and how do you determine that it is still running.

Comment: If autovacuum is too slow or can't keep up with your transaction rate, the usual approach is to make it **more** aggressive, not to disable it. I.e. lower the thresholds, give it more time to work